# Checking for duplicates and removing row from a DataTable but appending column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

have slightly tricky question. I have a datatable with thousands or rows. It has two columns. Using one of the column as the key i need to check for duplicates. If there there is I will need to add the value in the other column into one column and remove the duplicate row. I am able to find the duplicate and add the values. But when i remove one row, it affects the rest as the index have been changed. Plus I not sure if I am doing efficiently or not. Please advice.

```
   Cate_Id      TrxnCount
 ----------       ----------
    ER01              0
    ER02              0
    ER41              0
    ER53              1
    ER53              2
    ER56              0
    ER56              0
    ER56              0
    ER57              8
    ER57              9
```

After remmoving and adding the value

```
 Cate_Id           TrxnCount
 ----------       ----------
    ER01              0
    ER02              0
    ER41              0
    ER53              3 
    ER56              0
    ER57              17
```

How can I achieve this in the easist and efficent manner. Please advice.

Here is what i have done:

```
  List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();
  int newValue = 0;
  for (int i = 15; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    if (i > 0)
    {
       // Compare with previous row using index
      if (dt.Rows[i]["Cate_Id "].ToString() == dt.Rows[i - 1]["Cate_Id "].ToString())
      {
        newValue = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["TrxnCount"].ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i - 1]["TrxnCount"].ToString());
        dt.Rows[i]["TrxnCount"] = newValue;
        rowsToDelete.Add(dt.Rows[i - 1]);
         newValue = 0;
      }
    }
      if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
      {
        if (dt.Rows[i]["Cate_Id"].ToString() == dt.Rows[i + 1]["Cate_Id"].ToString())
        {
         newValue = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["TrxnCount"].ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i - 1]["TrxnCount"].ToString());
         dt.Rows[i]["TrxnCount"] = newValue;
         rowsToDelete.Add(dt.Rows[i - 1]);
         newValue = 0;
         }
       }     
   }


  foreach(var r inrowsToDelete )
  dt.Rows.Remove(r);
```

Comment: I've included a way to do it in the db side. If this is not what you need, please let meknow some more detailson what you're using this for, to give you an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that in the more efficient way you need to do it in the DB side.

You can write an stored procedure that does this:

- select the sum and count of the TrxnCount grouped by the Cate_Id, having count > 1
- store the result in a temp table of duplicates
- delete from the original table all the records whose Cate_Id exists in the temp table of duplicates
- insert all the values from the temp table into the original table

That's much more efficient that doing it in the client side.

BTW, this has a terrible design flaw: the table doesn't have a PK, which is very bad idea.

The code for tyhe Stored Procedure (I'm supposing the original table name is `T`)

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT Cate_Id, SUM(T.TrxnCount) AS TrxnCount 
INTO #dups
FROM T GROUP BY T.Cate_Id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

DELETE FROM T WHERE Cate_Id IN (SELECT Cate_Id FROM #dups)
INSERT INTO T SELECT * FROM #Dups

COMMIT TRAN
```